# Como enviar dois formulários em uma requisição via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Possuo alguns campos em uma pagina, que não posso colocar em um único formulário por conta da distancia entre os códigos, então agrupei em dois formularios que preciso enviar via Ajax.

ex:

```
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" name="nome" />
</form>

<form id="form2">
<input type="text" name="telefone" />
</form>
```

*Os formulários acima são hipotéticos, já que os meus possuem muitos campos.*

Já tentei agrupar os dois formulários com o .serialize() e com o FormData() mas não obtive sucesso.

ex:

```
$("#form2").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
     
        var pessoas = document.getElementById('form1');
        var telefones = document.getElementById('form2');

        formData = new FormData(pessoas);
        formData.append('tel', telefones);

        $.ajax({
            url: "<?= BASE_URL ?>ajax/teste",
            method: "POST",
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $('#resultado').val(response.mensagem);
            },
        });
})
```

No PHP eu consigo receber o campo nome do **form1**, mas não consigo receber nenhum campo do **form2**

Comment: não vai dar pra postar dois forms usando um object no data, poderia criar um objeto, por exemploe `var dados = { form1: new FormData(form1), form2: new FormData(form2) }`, mas se postar isso acho que o php não vai conseguir fazer POST para ler

Comment: @RicardoPontual mesmo erro, o form2 não é enviado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que não seja possível enviar dois formulários pela requisição AJAX, mas tenho um sugestão

Todos os campos que você for enviar para o AJAX, adicione uma classe para ele, exemplo "form-buscado".

Na sua função do AJAX, busque todos os campos que contem essa classe e armazena em um array

```
var ArrayDados = {};
$('.form-buscado').each(function(){
         ArrayDados[this.id] = this.value;
 });
```

No seu AJAX, passe o array

```
data: {
    dados: ArrayDados
}
```

E no PHP vc irá receber um ARRAY e poderá acessa-los com o ID do input.

Exemplo:

```
$VALORES_INPUT = $_POST['dados'];

$valor_cidade = $VALORES_INPUT['id_cidade'];
```